# получить String Literal Types из Object в runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript

В проекте используются `sass` для стилизации и `typescript` для типизации.

Есть набор констант который используется и стилях и интерфейсах реактовских компонентов. Это цвета.

Сейчас есть отдельно файл `colors.scss` вида

```
$white: white;
$brightest: #f0f0f0
...
```

И энум

```
enum Colors {
    WHITE = 'white',
    BRIGHTEST = 'brightest',
    ...
}
```

Хочется избежать поддержки двух файлов. **Можно ли как то в рантайме сгенерить тайпскриптовый тип?**

Пробовал так

**colors.scss**

```
$white: white;
$brightest: #f0f0f0
:export {
  white: $white;
  brightest: $brightest;
}
```

**somefile.ts**

```
import colors from "colors.scss";

function literalArray<K extends string>(args: K[]): K[] {
   return args;
}
 const ProxyProperties = literalArray(Object.keys(colors)); // так не работает
 // const ProxyProperties = literalArray(['white', 'brightest']); // а так работает

type colorsType = typeof ProxyProperties[number];

((v: colorsType) => console.log(v))("white");
((v: colorsType) => console.log(v))("red");
((v: colorsType) => console.log(v))('');
```

При таком подходе тип генерится только если явно в функцию передать массив, если его получить через `Object.keys` то вместо

```
type colorsType = 'white' | 'brightest'
```

получаем

```
type colorsType = string
```

Comment: а что выводит _Object.keys(colors)_?

Comment: то что нужно. масив, который если вписать напрямую дает желаемый результат

Comment: пробовал вместо импорта из scss вынести название и значение цветов в json обьект, а потом импортить его и в scss и в ts. Но все равно не получается из ключей этого обьекта получить юнион тип

Comment: можно попробовать `type colorsType = keyof colors;` но тогда colors возможно надо будет на что-то изменить

Comment: А еще можно попробовать так: `type colorsType = keyof typeof colors;`, в [песочнице вроде работает](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0Avar%20colors%20%3D%20%7B%20white%3A%201%2C%20brightest%3A%202%20%7D%3B%0Atype%20colorsType%20%3D%20keyof%20typeof%20colors%3B%0A%0A((v%3A%20colorsType)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(v))(%22white%22)%3B%0A((v%3A%20colorsType)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(v))(%22red%22)%3B%0A((v%3A%20colorsType)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(v))('')%3B)

Comment: в том то и проблема что при явном создании обьекта в текущей области видимости все отрабатывает (мой пример в вопросе который закоментирован) а вот если обьект импортить через `import` или `require` то вместо юнион тайпа по ключам получаю стринг

Comment: А ты пробовал именно мой вариант?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77017/discussion-between-torokhkun-and-grundy).